# Git - what is a correct way to fork a software

Tags: git

I would like to create a light fork of an opensource project. The fork would basically consist of very few small patches on top of it. But I'm not sure how to technically do this. Currently, I just have the patches as few commits on a branch and periodically rebase on the upstream branch as they release new version. However, I'm not sure if that is optimal since it requires `push --force` after each such rebase. So I'm curious how this should be correctly handled in theory.

Should I just have my own tree and just merge the changes instead of a rebase? Is there a recommended strategy to do this?

Comment: Create patch files you can apply using the `patch` program; then you just maintain them rather than forking the project at all.

Comment: If the fork is mainly for personal use, and you don't expect people to work on your fork, then using `push --force` is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Both strategies (merging or rebasing) are fine and will produce the same result.

You might be interested in [Patch Management](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/PatchManagement) tools such as:

- [Quilt](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/quilt)
- [StGit](http://www.procode.org/stgit/) (Stacked Git)